# CPU hot plugging and strict 1:1 threading

Tags: multithreading, affinity, hotplugging

I wish to add support for CPU hot plugging in my application that has strict affinity rules. Each physical core has exactly one thread pinned to it, but the logic I use for pinning a thread to a CPU is fairly naive and fails if a CPU between 0..N is offline.

I have chosen an approach where I have an array of size `MAX_CPU`, where each CPU on the system maps to a slot by its identifier. For example, CPU0 -> `threads[0]`, and CPU1 -> `threads[1]`, and so on. The idea is to mirror the system's setup.

```
for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    set_affinity(threads[i], i);
```

However, if an offline CPU is encountered anywhere but the end, it will fail.

To make things worse, when a CPU is taken offline during runtime, the pinned thread's affinity mask is reset without notice.

Ultimately, I hope to support complex setups like:

```
CPU0     CPU1      CPU2     CPU3
ONLINE   OFFLINE   ONLINE   OFFLINE
```

How can I incorporate awareness of online and offline CPU:s into my application?

I'm avoiding `/proc` and `/sys` as I'm interested in porting to other platforms, specifically various BSD:s. I use x86_64 for now, so the `cpuid` instruction may be useful.

Comment: "*I'm avoiding /proc and /sys as I'm interested in porting to other platforms*" - How are you currently accessing CPU online/offline status?

Comment: @ArjunShankar I can't access per-CPU status, but on Linux I can get the count of online and configured CPU:s using `sysconf(2)`. For now, I just optimistically pin N threads throughout CPU:s 0..N and let it fail for offline CPU:s. What I'm looking for is a reliable way to enforce each online CPU to have a thread pinned to it.

Comment: I don't see proper support for CPU hotplugging in FreeBSD, for example. I could be wrong because the only relevant result I found was [from 2009, and it was in the negative](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2009-April/005706.html).

Comment: On the other hand, there seems to be pretty good documentation about CPU hotplugging in Linux. [Here is a 2005 announcement on ML/LWN](http://lwn.net/Articles/159561/) about the 'new' documentation. And [here is the document itself](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt)

Comment: My point with the above being, I *think* you don't really have a way out but to write this stuff non-portably. I've never tried it, so I could be wrong. Everything I said above is a result of searches (which I did because I found your question interesting).

Comment: @ArjunShankar Thank you for your input. I feared it would be very platform specific and hacky. It looks like Linux is the only platform to take seriously on CPU hot plugging for now. This won't be pretty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `sched_getaffinity(2)` is awesome and better suited for this case. The `cpu_set_t` it fills in is not a generalized mask like `0xffffffff...` that would imply schedule anywhere, but actually a detailed and up-to-date mask of each *online* and *permitted* CPU. Using the `CPU_*` macros, it's possible to extract how many CPU:s are online and which.

```
cpu_set_t set;
int i, n;

if (sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &set))
    return;

n = CPU_COUNT(&set);

/* pin a thread to each online and permitted cpu */
for (i = 0; n; ++i)
    if (CPU_ISSET(i, &set)) {
        /* spawn a thread and pin it to cpu identified by 'i' ... */
        --n;
    }
```

When notified of a hot plug event, a call to `sched_getaffinity(2)` from a non-pinned thread will give us an updated mask.

An added benefit is awareness of utilities like `taskset(1)`.

FreeBSD has a `cpuset_getaffinity(2)` system call that probably operates in a similar fashion. I don't have access to try it out now.